# How to login a new user by default after mail Invite in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a requirement where I need to log in a new user to a Meteor application by default, and take the user to the reset password route after that.

I looked into this [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword), but I don't think it would apply here, because the password is not known. Here's my use case in detail :-

A user invites another new user by providing the invited user's email ID. The application sends email invite to the user, asking them to be taken to a route which normally requires logging into the application.

The new user who receives the email invite, is not yet signed up with the application. So, they need to pick a password to log in to the invited area of the application.

Currently, I am using the `meteor-useraccounts:core` package; to trigger the `resetPasswd` route for FlowRouter. Using the `onSubmitHook`, one can redirect the user to the proper location after successful reset of the password.

However, I am not able to figure out how to first log in the user automatically. Because if the user is not logged in, the reset password page won't open. Instead, it would show some error, indicating unauthorized action.

How could a link be sent via mail to the invited user, which would automatically log in the user?

Comment: Why does the reset password route require you to be logged in? Why not leave that outside of your authentication logic?

Comment: With [cloak.ly](https://cloak.ly) invitations take you to a *registration* page that allows the user to enter their email address and set their password. The page also tells you who invited you and when. Going through a reset cycle seems really weird. One of the interesting aspects of invitations is that the invitee may choose to register with a different email address (because for example you invited them via their work email but they want to register using a personal address).

Answer (score 1):

> I looked into this documentation, but I don't think it would apply
>   here, because the password is not known.

That is right, and because of that, in order to achieve that you have to create an account for that e-mail at the time the user enters a link sent by e-mail. Or create the account at time of invitation.

So possible solutions:

1) create an account for an e-mail provided in query (http://app/login?email=blabla@google.com) for a route, random password, reset password e-mail sent immediately after the login. (create login automatically login the user). That would also required some security key, so that no-one could create lots of accounts on different e-mail addresses.

2) create account at time of invitation, take random password and send it as a query parameter of the link sent to the invited user. When user enters the site, you take that password (and e-mail) and login him with that, and immediately send reset password for that e-mail